# PPTP VPN on Non-Standard Port

Tags: network-manager, vpn, dd-wrt

How can I run a VPN connection on a non-standard port? I have set up a VPN on my router running DD-WRT which I connected to my main router. I have forwarded the port to port 90 and can not connect to the VPN with the Network Manager. If I change the port back to 1723 (the default port) I can connect just fine. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here are the relevant IP addresses:

1.1.1.1=DD-WRT Router

192.168.1.154=IP on *Internet Router*

64.7.134.78=IP

I want it to work like this:

```
1.1.1.1:1723 > 192.168.1.154:1723 > 64.7.134.78:90
```

But it will only work like this:

```
1.1.1.1:1723 > 192.168.1.154:1723 > 64.7.134.78:1723
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you have forwarded the port to port 90 on the DD-WRT, is that correct?
Have you checked your iptables configuraton on the DD-WRT to ensure that your packets to that port will be received?

I don't currently know how to get Network Manager to PPTP to a specific port. I am looking into it and I will edit this answer when I find out.
You also might try appending the port number to the end of the IP address, like `192.168.1.1:90` for example.

I can't find any way to induce Network Manager to send to a custom port, unless the above suggestion works.

Looking at /usr/share/doc/pptp-linux/USING and at `man pppd` I don't see any way to specify a custom port either, unless, again, the method above works.

If it does not work, the best thing I can think of is to add a static route, defining the VPN's address range as the destination and the VPN tunnel exit address and port as the gateway. See `ip route help` for more information.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding. I will update my question. Using a : or :: (some apps use this) doesn't connect at all.

Comment: Do you control the host at 64.7.134.78? Have you verified that packets to port 90 are being received and not dropped?